# spark Optimize performance Structured Streaming Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spark-structured-streaming

two servers (4core+16GRAM) for test application

My idea is get data from kafka, process with **multi threads**, and save in `Elasticsearch`

```
spark-submit --class com.yizhisec.bigdata.TrafficEs 
--master yarn 
--deploy-mode cluster 
--executor-memory 512M 
--executor-cores 2 
--conf spark.streaming.concurrentJobs=5 
--num-executors 5 
--supervise bigdata-1.0.jar
```

[image]
but **only one task** in executors
[image]

code

I have use `numPartitions` to get data

```java
spark.readStream().format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", prop.getProperty("kafka.broker.list"))
                .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", prop.getProperty("kafka.jks.path"))
                .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password", prop.getProperty("kafka.jks.passwd"))
                .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SSL")
                .option("kafka.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "")
                .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
                .option("numPartitions", prop.getProperty("kafka.partition"))
                .option("subscribe", topic)
                .load()
                .selectExpr("CAST(topic AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)");
```

process code

```java
Dataset<Traffic> df = StreamSparkUtils.steamToTraffic(rawDf);
String[] appProtoFilter = properties.getProperty("appproto").split(",");

Dataset<TrafficNode> nodeDataset = df
        .filter(df.col("appproto").isin(appProtoFilter))
        .map(new MapFunction<Traffic, TrafficNode>() {
            @Override
            public TrafficNode call(Traffic traffic) throws Exception {
                TrafficNode n = new TrafficNode();
                n.setDestport(traffic.getDestport());
                n.setSrcip(traffic.getSrcip());
                n.setDestip(traffic.getDestip());
                n.setAppproto(traffic.getAppproto());
                n.setEndtime(traffic.getEnd_time());
                return n;
            }
        }, Encoders.bean(TrafficNode.class));




StreamingQuery query = null;
try {
    query = StreamSparkUtils.streamSinkEs(nodeDataset, "loh_traffic");
    query.awaitTermination();
} catch (IOException | StreamingQueryException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How to optimize it.

save in es

```java
public static StreamingQuery streamSinkEs(Dataset<?> dataSet, String index) throws IOException {
        Properties properties = readProp();
        return dataSet.writeStream()
                .option("es.nodes", properties.getProperty("es.nodes"))
                .option("es.port", properties.getProperty("es.port"))
                .option("checkpointLocation", properties.getProperty("es.checkpoint"))
                .format("es")
                .start(index);
    }
```

streamtoTraffic

```java
    public static Dataset<Traffic> steamToTraffic(Dataset<Row> df) {
        if (df == null) {
            return null;
        }

        StructType trafficSchema = new StructType()
                .add("guid", DataTypes.LongType)
                ...
                .add("downsize", DataTypes.LongType);

        Dataset<Row> ds = df.select(functions.from_json(df.col("value").cast(DataTypes.StringType), trafficSchema).as("data")).select("data.*");
        return ds.as(ExpressionEncoder.javaBean(Traffic.class));
    }
```

Comment: How many partitions does your Kafka topic have?

Comment: @mike only one for test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Applications that read from Kafka scale with the number of partitions in a topic.** As long as you have your data stored in only one partition your application can only use one single consumer to get the data.

In your case it does not matter how many executors you have in your Spark application as only one can read from the one partition. This is because in Kafka we have the concepts of a **Consumer Group**. If you want to improve performance you should increase the numbers of partitions in your Kafka topic.

Here is an excerpt of the [Kafa documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#kafka_mq) describing the interaction between consumer group and partitions:

> By having a notion of parallelism—the partition—within the topics, Kafka is able to provide both ordering guarantees and load balancing over a pool of consumer processes. This is achieved by assigning the partitions in the topic to the consumers in the consumer group so that each partition is consumed by exactly one consumer in the group. By doing this we ensure that the consumer is the only reader of that partition and consumes the data in order. Since there are many partitions this still balances the load over many consumer instances. Note however that there cannot be more consumer instances in a consumer group than partitions.